# C++ Variant of same underlying types

Tags: c++, types

I have a codebase using a std::variant of a few typedefs. 
Initially, these were different types but now they overlap like the example below

```cpp
typedef int TA;
typedef int TB;
std::variant<TA, TB> a(TA(1));
```

Is there a zero-overhead way to make this work? 
In Scala, I would use opaque types for this purpose, how's something similar achieved C++?

Comment: to make what work? What is wrong with what you have?

Comment: The zero-overhead mechanism is to use `int` instead of `std::variant`. If that's not what you mean, then I'm not sure what you're asking. Take a step back and explain what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Are these types always going to be the same going forward?  If so, get rid of the variant.  If not, then keep it.  It shouldn't cost you anything more than you were already using when the types were different.

Comment: If you need an `int` that is semantically a different denominated type from another `int`, consider holding the `int` in a struct wrapper.  `struct mile { int x; };` versus `struct inch { int x; };`

Comment: boost has `STRONG_TYPEDEF` if thats what you are looking for.

Comment: the question would be much more clear if you would add the resulting compiler error

Comment: There is also `enum class` that can be used if you have access to C++17 (you don't need C++17, but it makes it a lot easier to actually use the `enum class`)

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap the type inside a class:

```
struct TA {
    int value;
};

struct TB {
    int value;
};

std::variant<TA, TB> a(TA{1});
```

Now you have two distinct types that each contain an integer with no overhead, and can be distinguished within a variant.

---

There are some tricks to make a class behave like it was an integer in order to minimise the changes needed in the program. For example, you could define an implicit conversion operator to the underlying type. Such tricks can however be counter-intuitive as well, so use with care.