# query typedef alias in a template function

Tags: c++, typedef, type-traits, variant

AFAIU I cannot overload a function with a typedef alias that has the same underlying type.

```
typedef int NumA;
typedef int NumB;
void func(NumA x) {}
void func(NumB x) {}
```

MSVC gives `error C2084: function 'void func(NumA)' already has a body` for above code.

Is it possible to query the alias using type traits? Something like `is_same` but understands the alias? Below code cannot distinguish the two aliases because it uses `is_same`.

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

typedef int NumA;
typedef int NumB;

template <typename T>
void f() {
  if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, NumA>)
    std::cout << "NumA\n";      
  else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, NumB>)
    std::cout << "NumB\n";
}

int main() {
  f<NumA>(); // outputs NumA
  f<NumB>(); // outputs NumA
}
```

### My higher level goal

I'm writing a UI tool for Vulkan graphics library.

```
// vulkan_core.h
typedef uint32_t VkFlags;
typedef VkFlags VkAttachmentDescriptionFlags;
typedef VkFlags VkDependencyFlags;
```

where I'm drawing a different UI element based on the alias using a visitor pattern.

```
#include <variant>
#include <vector>

using Value = std::variant<VkDependencyFlags, VkAttachmentDescriptionFlags>;
std::vector uiElements<Value>; // holds a list of UI elements to be drawn

struct UIDrawer {
  void operator()(VkDependencyFlags& val) {
    // UI logic
  }
  void operator()(VkAttachmentDescriptionFlags& val) {
    // UI logic
  }
};

for(Value& val : uiElements) {
  std::visit(UIDrawer{}, val);
}
```

Things were fine until I hit these two Vulkan types with the same underlying type `uint32_t`. This is where I got the "function already has a body" error. I cannot change the library (`vulkan_core.h`). And was wondering whether there are means of querying the alias in C++.

I saw these previous questions from where I learned that I cannot overload.

- [Overloading member methods with typedef aliases as parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10582519/overloading-member-methods-with-typedef-aliases-as-parameters)
- [overloading for typedef parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10595114/overloading-for-typedef-parameters)

And the answer to below question suggests creating new classes that wrap underlying type. But I don't want to touch the third-party library I'm working with.

- [C++ Variant of same underlying types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62174846/c-variant-of-same-underlying-types)

Comment: Look for *"strong typedef"* (but as you cannot change the library, it won't help).

Comment: Aliases are indistingable from the aliased type (and so between each other).